# Replace NAs in one vector with sequential elements of another vector

Tags: r, vectorization

I'd like to replace NA elements of a vector with elements from a sequence, for example:

```
x <- c(1, NA, 5, NA, NA, 2, 12, NA)
replace.seq <- -1:-4  # Can assume length(replace.seq) == sum(is.na(x))
goal <- c(1, -1, 5, -2, -3, 2, 12, -4)
```

What's an efficient way to do this? I'd prefer to avoid sorting `x`.

Comment: `x[is.na(x)] <- replace.seq`

Comment: May I recommend you change the title to "replace NAs in one vector with sequential elements of another vector" ?  Just makes it a bit more clear.  For comparison, `zoo::locf` replaces `NA` with the forward-looking value in the same vector; reversing the order of the vector would allow a look-back fill.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft agreed, that's clearer. Changed now, thanks.

Comment: @akrun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423931/extract-data-from-raw-html-in-r Can you please help with this question?

Answer (score 2):

Per @akrun:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- replace.seq
```

Comment: Should point out that `R` will recycle values as needed, so you should be careful about what you want to do if you have fewer values in `replace.seq` than `NA`s in your input vector.

Comment: alternatively: `x <- ifelse(is.na(x),replce.seq,x)`, but the above answer is the more traditional way

Comment: @Sven really?  `x[is.na(x)] <- replace.seq;y <- ifelse(is.na(x),replce.seq,x); identical(x,y)` evaluates to `TRUE` for me.

Comment: @Jthorpe Yes, really. After the first command, `x` doesn't contain any `NA`s. Try `x <- c(1, NA, 5, NA, NA, 2, 12, NA);
y <- ifelse(is.na(x), replace.seq, x); 
x[is.na(x)] <- replace.seq;
identical(x,y)`.

Comment: `ifelse` fails because it recycles values of `replace.seq` based on the index in `x`. It returns `c(1, -2,  5, -4, -1, 2, 12, -4)`, where the first -2 comes because it's the second element of `x`, -4 as fourth element, -1 again as fifth element (recycled to first), etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace`:

```
x <- replace(x, is.na(x), replace.seq)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better if you want to produce a new vector.